# Using handwriting font in proofs

Tags: fonts

I read several posts but still could not figure out how to do the following. I want to use handwriting font, say, Augie font, within proof environment. I installed the package **emerald**. Then I read someone suggested to define a new environment like

```
\newenvironment{myfont}{\fontfamily{<familyname>}\selectfont}{\par}
```

I could not make it work since I could not find its font family in the first place. Could any one provide me with a concrete example, please? Thank you! Here is the codes I have at the moment.

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps, .pdf, .jpeg, .png}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{emerald}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=10mm,
 bottom=10mm
 }

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1,0,0}

\newenvironment{myfont}{\fontfamily{<familyname>}\selectfont}{\par}

\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\newcommand*\ruleline[1]{\par\noindent\raisebox{.8ex}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-.8ex}{#1}\hspace{1ex}\hrulefill}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Question One}

\begin{proof}
\begin{myfont}
  Some text in the new font.
\end{myfont}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you want to use a environment just for the restricted usage of the font?

Comment: `\ECFAugie This is Augie font`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added my codes in my question. I only want to use Augie in proof maybe with a different color.

Comment: @XuShi: See the comment by HarishKumar: Use that command inside the envr. instead of `\fontfamily ... \selectfont` if you want to restrict the font within the proof to some part only and use other fonts in other parts of the proof.

Comment: @HarishKumar Do you mean to write \newenvironment{myfont}{\fontfamily{<\ECFAugie>}\selectfont}{\par}?

Comment: No! Just do `\begin{proof}
\ECFAugie
  Some text in the new font.
\end{proof}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have these options:

Use `\newenvironment{myfont}{\fontfamily{augie}\selectfont}{\par}`

Then it boils down to

```
\begin{proof}
\begin{myfont}
  Some text in the new font.
\end{myfont}
\end{proof}
```

Or use the switch `\ECFAugie`

```
\begin{proof}
\ECFAugie
  Some text in the new font.
\end{proof}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps, .pdf, .jpeg, .png}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{emerald}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=10mm,
 bottom=10mm
 }

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1,0,0}

\newenvironment{myfont}{\fontfamily{augie}\selectfont}{\par}

\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\newcommand*\ruleline[1]{\par\noindent\raisebox{.8ex}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-.8ex}{#1}\hspace{1ex}\hrulefill}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Question One}

\begin{proof}
\begin{myfont}
  Some text in the new font.
\end{myfont}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
\ECFAugie
  Some text in the new font.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may use `etoolbox` and its macro `\AtBeginEnvironment` to hook in to the proof environment so that some typing is saved. That is a different story.

Bonus: Some hand written fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{emerald}% 1
\usepackage{aurical}% 2
\usepackage{pbsi}% 3

%\usepackage{chancery}%Zapf chancery font

\usepackage{la}
\newcommand{\setfont}[2]{{\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont #2}}
\begin{document}
\noindent\setfont{frc}{\Huge This is french cursive font.}\\[5pt]
\setfont{calligra}{\Huge This is Calligra font.}\\[5pt]
\setfont{pzc}{\Huge This is chancery font.}\\[5pt]
 %{\Huge\itshape This is chancery italic font.}\\[5pt]
\section{Augie} {\ECFAugie This is Augie font --1.}\\[5pt]
\section{Auriocus Kalligraphicus} {\Fontauri This is Auriocus Kalligraphicus font --2.}\\[5pt]
\section{BrushScriptX-Italic} {\bsifamily This is BrushScriptX-Italic font --3.}\\[5pt]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is for Nasser. As Jim Hefferon and LaRiFaRi said i comments, you can download a free font ([from here](http://ttfonts.net/download/37511.htm), and [here](http://www.911fonts.com/cyrrukopisnye/), say) and use xelatex or lualatex to get what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,  
]{Stylus ITC TT}

\begin{document}
  This is some TEXT.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you know by any chance if there is a font or package to do Architectural writing as well? As in this image ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cwOMz.png)  There are many links on the web on this subject as well. http://idesign93.blogspot.com/2013/09/architectural-lettering.html  it will be great if one can use this in Latex, in the main text itself, to replace the standard text with. (not for math environment)

Comment: If you are willing to use Lua- or XeLaTeX you may use any font you are able to download or purchase. Just search this side for the package `fontspec`.

Comment: On the architectural-lettering page, the first looks like Stylus ITC Regular to me.  You can get it online as a ttf (I don't know what it costs) and use, say, XeLaTeX, as already noted.

Comment: fyi, on texlive 2014 on Linux, I get the error `(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fundus-calligra/calligra.sty) ! LaTeX Error: File emerald.sty not found.`  but using Miktex on windows, it compiles with no error: `Making callig15.tfm from "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\calligra\callig15.mf"...
Running miktex-mf.exe...` and the PDF is produced ok.

Comment: Thanks, that looks really nice. I tried to compile it with pdflatex but said I need to xelatex. But when I did, it is missing the font. So I need to follow the links you have and figure how to install those font. I never done this before, and never used xelatex nor lualatex . I wonder if this will also work or can work with tex4ht? I guess I have some reading to do on xelatex. btw, why can't one use latex to compile this? Why one has to use xelatex? (tex4ht uses latex not xelatex). Is it possible to make this work with latex and pdflatex?

Comment: Would you know which specific font I need to install? the links you have there have so many fonts, and I have no idea what I am looking for. Sorry, I do not know anything about fonts and what font you are using for the `\setmainfont[  Ligatures=TeX,  ]{Stylus ITC TT}` If you have direct link to the font files I need that will be great.

Comment: @Nasser latex can not use system fonts. You need xelatex/lualatex for that. I have no idea about tex4ht though. Here is the link for font: http://www.911fonts.com/font/download_StylusITCTTRegular_66.htm . Download link is at the bottom right (next to Stylus TT Bold). If you want to use ttf or otf fonts, you need xe/lualatex. latex uses type1 fonts.